# Compiling with apxs , config_vars.mk not found

Tags: apache, module, centos

I am knew to programming apache modules, so I started with a tutorial to write simple programs.

having written my first mod_example.c I wanted to compile it with

```
apxs -i -a -c mod_example.c
```

However, I get the following error message:

`cannot open /usr/local/apache/build/config_vars.mk: No such file or directory at /usr/bin/apxs line 203`

I am running a Centos 6 with Apache 2.4 on it.

Any idea how this might get fixed?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the perl script `apxs` looking in the wrong directory for your httpd build directory.

You can either edit `/usr/bin/apxs` to change path to your build directory. The line you need to edit looks like this:

```
my $installbuilddir = "/usr/local/httpd/build";
```

Or you can just create a symlink instead:

```
ln -s /path/to/your/httpd/build /usr/local/httpd/build
```

Then use apxs from your unpacked httpd source code folder:

```
apxs -i -a -c ./modules/example/mod_example.c
```